# Data successfully export to Excel from gridview except ID column

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel-2010

Here is my code...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);

Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Visible = true;

ws.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";
ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Detail";
ws.Cells[1, 4] = "Category";
ws.Cells[1, 5] = "Brand";
ws.Cells[1, 6] = "In Stock";
ws.Cells[1, 7] = "Price";
ws.Cells[1, 8] = "Total";

for (int i = 2; i <= dgDetail.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 2; j <= 8; j++)
    {
        ws.Cells[i, j] = dgDetail.Rows[i - 2].Cells[j - 1].Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel has 1,1 based arrays, the first cell is 1,1, so you did it right when you put "ID" to this cell. Your gridview looks zero-based.
1) You start to export dgDetail from row 0, which I think is right, but you skip one last row - you can rewrite your code a little bit to see it:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dgDetail.Rows.Count-2; i++) {
        dgDetail.Rows[i]; //pseudocode
}
```

Maybe it's how you planned it, but you don't export row dgDetail.Row.Count - 1

2)

```
for (int j = 2; j <= 8; j++) {
    ws.Cells[i, j] = dgDetail.Rows[i - 2].Cells[j - 1].Value;
}
```

Here you need to change the first value of j to 1, because you start from second column otherwise:

```
ws.Cells[i, 2] = dgDetail.Rows[i - 2].Cells[2 - 1].Value;
```

I guess you are just confused by excel 1,1 based arrays a little bit,

Also, if you have big exports, it's better to write the whole array in one operation:

```
        Range range = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[1, 1], worksheet.Cells[2, 2]];
        range.Value = new object[2, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
```

Comment: Thnx Alex.. i tried all the above suggestions but cant find any way to sort this , this is my first that im working with excel..its my client requirement. I found one solution i know this is not the best way to do .. i added one extra column before ID column in database , and its working fine but i want to learn how to sort out this mess

Comment: It's very simple. As I said, your title indices are from 1 to 8. And in the cycle you write from index 2 to 8. This is how you lost your ID column.

Comment: ok, i understand but the reason to make it 2 to 8 is if i write 1 instead of 2 it gives me error of index out of range

Comment: out of range in ws.Cells[i, j] or dgDetail.Rows[i - 2].Cells[j - 1]?

Comment: woohooo thnx Alex u gave me the point to think Here is the solution for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++)  case solved..Thnx again

Comment: yeah, this is exactly how I told you in my answer.